# Why is Thunderbolt 3 a rarity on desktop computers?

Tags: thunderbolt

Most recent higher-end laptops seems to have a Thunderbolt 3 connection. However, this does not seem to be case for recent motherboards or graphics cards for desktop computers.

I know that one application of Thunderbolt 3 is connecting external GPUs, which is a laptop-specific need. However, Thunderbolt 3 has other uses as well:

- Seems to provide access to the PCI Express bus in general (although I do not know whether there is any other practical application for this than external GPUs).
- Can provide a high-bandwidth video signal for external displays.

At least the latter would seem to be useful on desktop computers as well. Why is Thunderbolt a mostly laptop-only technology then?

Comment: (This is primarily opinion) Re: Video Signal: Won't desktop motherboard already have multiple video output (VGA / DVI / HDMI / DP) - so there is little need for another one? TB3 is nice and small, which the compactness of that port is definitely a plus for laptop, but for a desktop PC that have built-in multiple-port video output... (and if you add a discrete GPU). Re: PCIe bus access - do you have a TB3 capable external drive? Exist, but rare.

Comment: Thunderbolt is primarily a data transfer, the fact it can connect to an eGPU, is due to the transfer speeds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so much being a laptop-only technology but rather it just being that motherboards for desktop computers usually have multiple [PCI-Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) slots.

PCI-Express has many different [hardware protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#Hardware_protocol_summary) and most motherboards for desktop computers often have;

- At least one **PCI-E x16/x8/x4 slot** that is utilised by graphics cards, which already use the hardware standard outputs for current display input standards (HDMI/DVI-D/Display Port) and,
- At least one **PCI-E x1 slot** for utilisation by storage expansions peripherals that use [SATA Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SATA_Express) or [NVM Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVM_Express).

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few reasons why Thunderbolt 3 is not that popular with desktop computers:

1. Desktop computers usually come with of multiple [PCIe slots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) providing plenty of flexibility when it comes to upgrading. For many applications installing a PCIe card might be more elegant (less cables and boxes on the desk) than connecting an external device using Thunderbolt 3. If an external device is desired today, USB 3 is often sufficient.
2. Thunderbolt 3 needs quite a few PCIe lanes to connect to the CPU (up to 4 PCIe lanes can be transmitted through Thunderbolt 3). Thus offering a few Thunderbolt 3 ports might drive up the price. Price is key in most parts of the main-board market. Note that a few main-board manufacturers sell expansion cards that add Thunderbolt 3, though.
3. Each Thunderbolt 3 port [is supposed to provide at least 15 W power to connected devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(interface)#Thunderbolt_3). Even x4 and wider PCIe expansion cards [are limited to a total power consumption of 25 W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#Power). A dual Thunderbolt 3 card thus would need an additional power cable from the PCs power supply to provide 15 W to each port. A x16 slot can provide more power but it's usually occupied by the video card.
4. Thunderbolt 3 is supposed to carry video signals which on a modular desktop computer usually emerge from a discrete video card or a connector at the rear of the main board. The video signal has to be routed from the DisplayPort output of the graphics card into the expansion card where the Thunderbolt 3 controller combines it with the USB/PCIe signal to Thunderbolt 3. The length of the required cable can be very different for integrated graphics vs. PCIe video cards - not the most elegant solution.

All this is much easier in a laptop where all components are fixed and soldered onto the same board.